# Android SurfaceView only plays first video , on sencond the screen freeze with last video frame and only sound is played

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview

Below is my code implementation for playing audio/ video files from sd card sequentially. The first video plays fine, but when the second video is played only sound is played  the screen freeze with the last frame of the first video. Please help to solve the issue.

```
package com.example.seqaudiovideo;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    static String[] mFiles=null;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;

     MediaPlayer mp ;


    int mNext;


    //On Complete Event Handler
    OnCompletionListener mListener = new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();          
            startNextFile();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // usual onCreate stuff 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       //Getting the Files 
        Songs s = new Songs();
        mFiles = s.getMediaList();
        mNext = 0;
        startNextFile();
    }

    public void startNextFile() {


        final SurfaceView  mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
        holder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);   


        if (mNext < mFiles.length) {
            try
         {

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(mFiles[mNext++]);           
            mp = new MediaPlayer();         
            mp.setDataSource(this, uri);
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(mListener);
            //surfaceCreated(holder);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();

         }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Er1", e.toString());

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        mp.setDisplay(holder);


    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a new MediaPlayer object for every movie in `startNextFile()`, but you're calling `mp.setDisplay()` in `surfaceCreated()`.  The `surfaceCreated()` callback is only called once, when the surface is initially created.  So your second and subsequent MediaPlayer objects never have `setDisplay()` called on them.

One way to handle this would be to set a flag in `surfaceCreated()`, and if it's set, just call `mp.setDisplay()` from `startNextFile()`.

Comment: I did as what you explained and it worked fine. thanks very much .